# AS3 Appending text at Caret

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, text

Working on a virtual keyboard using flash pro, and im somewhat stuck. 
I have a way to control the carat so you can scroll through the text field but I'd like to be able to punch in letters exactly where the carat is using code.

Below is my keyboard controls

```
// keyboard controls
for (var i=0; i<lettersSmall.length; i++)
{
    this["key_" + lettersSmall.charAt(i)].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,_keys);
    letterButtonSmall["key_" + lettersSmall.charAt(i)] = lettersSmall.charAt(i);
    letterButtonCaps["key_" + lettersSmall.charAt(i)] = lettersCaps.charAt(i);
}



function _keys(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    curTextPos = textSelect.caretIndex;
    strehrows3();
    stage.focus = textSelect;

    textSelect.setSelection(curTextPos,curTextPos);
    if (electoff.currentFrame == 2)
    {
        ajWidth(event);
    }
    if (terminalinput.currentFrame == 2)
    {
        TrWidth(null);
    }
    if (control == "on" && menu1.visible == false )
    {
        if (! shift)
        {
            textSelect.appendText(letterButtonSmall[event.target.name]);
            inputMaxWidth = textSelect.width;
        }
        else
        {
            textSelect.appendText(letterButtonCaps[event.target.name]);

            shift = false;
            inputMaxWidth = textSelect.width;
        }
        savedTxt = textSelect.text;
        textSelect.setSelection(textSelect.length,textSelect.length);
        if (textSelect.width <= 134.05)
        {
            //textSelect.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            textSelect.x = 1.2;
        }
        if (textSelect.width >= 134.05)
        {
            //textSelect.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            textSelect.x =  1.2-(textSelect.width-134.05);
        }
    }
    textSelect.setSelection(textSelect.length,textSelect.length);
    if (electoff.currentFrame == 2)
    {
        ajWidth(event);
    }
    if (terminalinput.currentFrame == 2)
    {
        TrWidth(null);
    }

    focuser();
    strehrows3();
    _fontSize();
    textSelect.width = inputMaxWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
var inputStr:String = event.target.name; //This looks like it's value of your key pressed?
var caret:int = textSelect.textField.caretIndex;
var afterCaretText:String = textSelect.text.substr(caret);
var beforeCaretText:String = textSelect.text.substr(0,caret);

textSelect.text = beforeCaretText + inputStr + afterCaretText;
```

You could do this all in one line without creating the four variables, but I think it's easier to understand what's going on like this.